# Get method name and parameters when it's invoked through a task queue

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I have a simple task queue that allows one task to execute at a time:

```
 public class TaskQueue
{
    public SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    public TaskQueue()
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    }

    public async Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {       
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public async Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

And I would queue a task in there like so:

```
private async Task SaveData()
{
    //some code
    await taskQueue.Enqueue(async () => { printed = await pm.Print(Template); });
    //some code
}
```

Now what I would like to do is inside the `Enqueue` method add a log that will contain the info `$Print was called with parameter {Template}`. **How can I get the name of the method executed and it's parameters?**

I know I can do `[CallerMemberName] string caller = ""` to get info that the call was made inside `SaveData`, but is there an attribute or something to log the info I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is *possible* (expression trees, etc), but it is *incredibly* inefficient; perhaps a better approach is to enqueue an object instead, i.e.

```cs
abstract class ThingToDo {
    public abstract Task DoTheThingAsync();
}
```

and make your queue a queue of `ThingToDo` instead of `Func<Task<T>>`, then you can have things like:

```cs
sealed class PrintThing : ThingToDo {
    private readonly int x;
    private readonly string y;
    private readonly string caller;
    public PrintThing(int x, string y, [CallerMemberName] string caller = null) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.caller = caller;
    }
    public override Task DoTheThingAsync() {...}
    public override ToString() => $"{nameof(PrintThing)}, x={x}, y={y} from {caller}";
}
```

and now you can output the task trivially.

In reality, this isn't all that different to what the compiler would generate *anyway* for a lambda/anonymous method with captured variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the log into the different methods. That way you can also specialize the log messages produced by each method.